# rewrite http[s] requests in firefox

Tags: firefox

is there any way to change the HTTP-request while loading a page in Firefox by adding a plugins or setting a config?
for example i want to change

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_something_

to :

https://myRouter_of_youtube.com/watch?v=_something_

i want to set int once and it works until changing that
I'm using Tamper Data but its not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want an encrypted connection to myRouter_of_youtube.com, and the an unencryptet connection from myRouter_of_youtube.com to youtube.com? Probably to leave someone in the local network unaware of your network actions? That would sound like a job for a proxy to me. You could either tunnel to an SSH-Server somewhere and use socks, or you use an HTTP proxy like squid.

Comment: No, I have access to myRouter... directly and **I dont want or need to use proxy server**. just I want is to request myRouter... instead of youtube it self, and other request not changed.